# Import from @types file that starts with `declare namespace`

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to work with the @types/googlemaps type definitions and am running into errors.

I have tried both

`import {google.maps.Map} from "googlemaps";`

`import * as google from "googlemaps";`

and variations.  The definition file starts with `declare namespace google.maps {...}` whereas I am more acquainted with `export module Foo{...}`

the error I get is

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './config/constants' in 'app_path/node_modules/googlemaps/lib'`

Comment: Have you installed both the normal package and `@types`? Are you importing the real package or trying to import the `@types` package?

Comment: @ssube I have installed both, and my import statement looks as is.